# Windows 11 ARM - Visual studio IIS Express crash

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis-express, windows-11

I have a Windows 11 Pro(Version 22H2) 64bit ARM VM created with Parallels (Version 18.0.1 (53056))
I installed net core 5 and 6 for ARM (SDK and hosting bundle)
I created a new net core web application but when I start debug IIS Express didn't start and event viewer error is:

> The Module DLL 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core
> Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll' could not be loaded due to a configuration
> problem. The current configuration only supports loading images built
> for a AMD64 processor architecture

I tried to change app URL port number, delete .vs folder and IIS debug instead of IIS Express

Always the same error

Comment: Well... isn't it because an Arm processor would be using arm64 instead of AMD64?

Comment: yes, indeed I installed net core for ARM but I have this error. I add it to my question

Comment: What target version of Net is you project using?  Open csproj file with notepad and look for target.

Comment: As a preview release of VS for ARM64, all kinds of bugs are expected so your only option is to report to Microsoft and wait for fixes.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8249 I saw this thread, similar to your question.

Comment: Net version is Net Core 5

Comment: In the past I installed Windows 11 ARM Insider Preview and IIS Express (with the same VS project now I have the problem) worked perfectly. So it's strange what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [a very detailed article on Windows 11 ARM64 full IIS and ASP.NET Core](https://halfblood.pro/successful-and-failed-attempt-my-first-pull-request-for-asp-net-core/). But the IIS Express scenario seems to be different.

Will go back to make a complete answer when I have time to finish more investigation.

A few interesting facts so far for future readers,

1. `C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe` is ARM64X executable.
2. ASP.NET Core module files under `C:\Program Files\IIS Express\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\` are pure ARM64.
3. Based on the error message posted by you, `C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll` was likely to be pure ARM64, while the IIS Express worker process seemed to be running as x64.

You will have to provide more information like what exactly you installed on this VM, because

- .NET 5/6 do not have ARM64 support, so installing them only add x64 bits to ``C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2`. That is contradictory to 3. My guess is somehow you got .NET 7 bits installed.
- Also interesting why your IIS Express worker process tried to load ASP.NET Core module bits from `C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2`. That makes no sense as if you read `C:\Program Files\IIS Express\AppServer\applicationhost.config` (template for VS to create all other config files) it points to `C:\Program Files\IIS Express\Asp.Net Core Module\V2` by default. There must be something you didn't reveal before hitting this issue.

You didn't mention the Visual Studio release you were using either. That might also contribute to the problem.